# How to fetch address and modify the value in key/value format file?

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, awk

I'm currently writing a shell-script for my Raspberry Pi so it sets up an access-point with a unique SSID.
To do this I want to use the mac-address of the WiFi dongle as my SSID. For doing that I want to use awk,
with

```
awk '{ gsub(/:/, ""); print > "file" }' /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

I can write the properly formatted mac address to a file, but how can I insert it into a specific line/place at another file?
I have in mind something like

```
awk '{ gsub(/:/, ""); "replace ssid= at /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"  }' /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

Any help plus explanation for a newbie like me is appreciated.

---

My input file is like:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
01:23:45:67:89:ab
```

and I'm trying to fetch it and replace the value of `ssid` in the file which is like:

```
interface=wlan0 driver=nl80211 ssid=7cdd907f6b07 hw_mode=g channel=11 macaddr_acl=0 auth_algs=1 ignore_broadcast_ssid=0 wpa=1 wpa_passphrase=My_Passphrase wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK wpa_pairwise=TKIP rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Comment: Can you paste some example content of /sys/class/net/wlan0/address to parse? And what are you expected results?

Comment: @kenorb the content is a mac address: `7c:dd:90:7f:6b:07` and the expected results are `ssid=pi_7cdd907f6b07` within the `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

Comment: Just single line with something like `01:23:45:67:89:ab`? Can you simply use `grep`: `grep -o ..:..:..:..:..:.. >> file`? Or the issue is rather that you want it at the particular line? Do you have `ex` in Rasberry Pi?

Comment: I have multiple lines within the `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` - I just need to modify the one with `ssid=some_ssid` - the `grep` command just writes to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{gsub(":","");macadd=$0;next}{sub(/^ssid=.*/,"ssid="macadd)}1' /sys/class/net/wlan0/address /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Current record no. (`NR`) equals current file record no. just for the first file, then `:`'s substitution is done, subsequently the line is placed on the `macadd` variable, and `next` skips line output.

The other instructions are applied to the `hostapd.conf` file; final `1` stands for "true", thus lines are printed.

If everyting works fine, you may redirect command output to a new file, and replace `hostapd.conf`.

Notes:

- files order **does** matter, as you can tell
- `gawk` features in-place replacement starting from 4.1.0

Comment: perfect! exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! A remark, although you've probably stepped into this definition: when you read "record" in awk, you may think of a line (as in this case) or part of it (a "field")

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bak "s/^ssid=.*/ssid=$(tr -d ':'</sys/class/net/wlan0/address|tee file)/" /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Once tested, you can remove the `.bak` part, which creates a backup of `hostapd.conf`. I think you are also going to delete `|tee file`.

The `^` sign in regexps stands for "beginning of line"; the `s` operator in `sed` substitutes a regexp with a given string. Given string here has a subshell called thru `$(...)`, getting `address` content, purging it from `:`'s with `tr`, and returning the output after a copy is stored into the `file` file by the `tee` command.

Comment: Your answer is helpful and works, although I'm specifically looking for a `awk` solution.

Comment: will the whole line be replaced or just `ssid:=`?

Comment: No colon in my regexp. Rules that apply: `^` means start of line; `.` means any single character; `a*` means zero or more of a. [Test it](http://rubular.com/r/TG2Z066u0M) yourself. BTW, did you miss the `awk` solution I tried to write down?

Answer (score 0):

Then load and save it in-place using `ex` editor, try:

```
ex +'let @m = substitute(system("cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address"), "[^0-9a-z]", "", "g")' +'%s/ssid=\zs[a-f0-9]\{12}/\=@m/' -scwq /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

which:

- takes MAC address from the file (`system("cat file")` which is equivalent to `readfile('file')`
- substitute output by removing everything exempt `[0-9a-z]`
- then assign it into `@m` register
- then substitute on `hostapd.conf` by finding `ssid` and replacing `\{12}` characters of `[a-f0-9]` with value of `m` register (`\=@m`),

  in other words, it's like: `%s/^key=\zs.\+/new_value/`
- then save the file in-place (`-cwq`)

To debug it, you may:

- add extra `+%p` (to print it) and change `-scwq` into `-scq!` for dry-run (without changing the file)
- add `-V1` for more verbose

---

To fetch just MAC address from `ifconfig` it's easy to do with `grep`, like:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | egrep -om1 "..(:..){5}"
```

or:

```
grep -o ..:..:..:..:..:.. <(ifconfig wlan0)
```